# Horizontal RecyclerView scrolling in Cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

In my android application I have a vertical RecyclerView with Cardviews. In each Card I have horizontal RecyclerView that can be scrolled if all elements can't be viewed on screen.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j54bJ.png)

Also I have swipe functionality for deleting cards. So when I try to scroll my horizontal recycler I want it to be scrolled, but cardview is being swiped instead. How can I disable (maybe) swiping if user touched RecyclerView.

For recyclers I am using PlaceHolderView lib.